# fill a pivot table with all possible instances in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two tables: **days** and **times**. These tables have a N:N relationship with each other.So I used a pivot table for them: **days_times**.
In my view I need a button when clicked,fills the pivot table with all the possible instances.
for example if there are 2 records in **days** and 2 records in **times**,the pivot table after the process should has 4 records:
`day_id | time_id`
`1      |       1`
`1      |       2`
`2      |       1`
`2      |       2`

Let's consider an action like `ScheduleController@fill` wants to take care of this process. How should I achieved this?

Comment: Obviously! that shouldn't have gone for another question mate :) my bad.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk no problem my friend :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer,I don't know if there is a better solution:

```
public function fill(){
    $days = Day::all();
    foreach($days as $day)
    {
        $times = Time::all();
        foreach($times as $time)
        {
            $day->times()->attach($time->id);
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is not efficient but at least it works.